UK visa form help
I entered the wrong employment join dates previously 2 yrs ago, when I filled the short stay visa form for the UK. The year was correct but I mentioned the wrong month.
Should I mention the right dates this time or just enter the previously entered dates?

Are you now filling-in a new UK visa application ?

Yes i am.filling in a new application

What date is stated in your employment contract?

Always answer truthfully.
It is better for you to be discovered attempting to correct an old mistake than to be discovered trying to deliberately and knowingly perpetuate a falsehood. The latter is obviously regarded as deliberate deceit and is likely to have far worse outcomes for you if detected.

I didnt mention the wrong date on purpose. Its my family owned business where i work so theres no specific date to be sure. However i recently checked the first visa stamping date which was a month or two forward than the date i mentioned previously in d form. Year was always correct

The circumstances doesn't really matter in relation to the advice in this answer, which I'll repeat because it good advice: "Always answer truthfully."
